# Function vba works but when clicked on shows 0

Tags: excel, vba

So ive created a function using VBA that removes the characters from a cell

```
Function removeAlpha(r As String) As String
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "[A-Za-z]"
    .Global = True
    removeAlpha = .Replace(r, "")
End With
End Function
```

It's saved as an add in and accessible in all workbooks

I'm trying to create a macro that uses this function for cells in another workbook, so what i want it to do is paste the values from the active sheet onto another sheet without the characters.

```
Set wsDest = Workbooks("Bill.csv").Worksheets("Bill")
Lastrow = wsDest.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Row
Set NextFreeCell = wsDest.Cells(Lastrow, "AC")

NextFreeCell.Formula = "=removeAlpha(" & Cells(i + 1, j + 5).Address(external:=True) & ")"
```

The formula works, and in the destination worksheet the values are there and it shows that the formula has worked, but when i click on the cell and click anywhere in the formula and press enter, it then shows 0 and im not sure why this is happening.

First Bill is the active sheet

```
=removeAlpha('[FirstBill.xlsx]Table 1'!$G$10)
```

This is what is shown when i click on the cell that has the formula in the destination worksheet, and will show the correct value but when i click enter it shows 0.  Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i've omitted a lot of rows in the second block of code just for conciseness, but am happy to give more details if required

Comment: thought it might be due to the csv format, so have saved it as a workbook and changed the relevant lines in vba, but still not working